# iPhone assembly GAS directive declare a extern function

Tags: iphone, assembly, directive

In a assembly code for iPhone GCC4.2, how to delare a extern function?
Example:

```
_main:
    bl myfunc
    bx lr
```

We know if a common compiler, we can use "import myfunc" or "extern myfunc" to declare this function, but GCC44.2 in iOS developer doesn't recognize them.

Answer (score 0):

Apple's GAS is a very old fork. I think it wants ".globl". Check [this doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/Assembler/040-Assembler_Directives/asm_directives.html).

Comment: but i meant the myfunc(), not the _main().

Comment: like:
.globl _main
.extern myfunc //here extern is wrong, I wonderd which one is correct?.indirect_symbol?.reference?
_main:
     bl myfunc
     bx lr

Comment: actually it need not to declare the called symbol here.